# Ambiguous call using extension methods in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, extension-methods

When calling an extension method from another extension method, my solution was building ok, but in the published site (or the virtual asp.net server) I was getting the Compile Error "Ambiguous call".

```
public static string ExtensionMethodA(this ObjectToExtend myObj){//code here}

public static string ExtensionMethodB(this ObjectToExtend myObj){
   string a = myObj.ExtensionMethodA(); // this line causes the error.
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't read enough to know exactly why, but here is the solution:

```
public static string ExtensionMethodA(this ObjectToExtend myObj){//code here}

public static string ExtensionMethodB(this ObjectToExtend myObj){
    string a = ExtensionMethodA(myObj); // correct call.
    return a;
 }
```

Comment: The better thing to do would have been to edit your question and ask WHY this behavior is like this.  From your Q&A it looks like you are explicitly calling one method instead of another so why does passing the object make a difference?